# Why shell_exec doesn't see path environment variable

Tags: python, shell

Works:

```
shell_exec('c:\python27\python.exe command.py');
```

Works in shell:

```
python.exe command.py
```

Doesn't work:

```
shell_exec('python.exe command.py');
```

OS is windows 7. This works on debian and on other windows 7 computer, but on my computer it doesn't. What can be the reason?

Comment: Because the shell as your user has a path variable.  The IUSR webserver user does not.  This is the same with the Apache user normally, on both Windows and Linux.

Comment: Both windows 7 computers have apache.

Answer (score 0):

When you run command line from your user account `python` path is set in a path variable .

If it doesn't work, it means that the `webserver user` does not have it set. check this [thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/151328/setting-apache2-path-environment-variable) on how to set `PATH` variable apache 2 .

Comment: Thank you, but I didn't find how to set apache path environment variable on windows.

Comment: @ИванПетров check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22652843/changing-path-environment-variable-in-apache-windows-xampp . he mentions adding environment variables and then reinstalling xampp fixes it for him. but got no answer on how to edit them.
i will give it a check when i use my windows machine.